# Saving loop results R

Tags: r

Please tell me how can I save my loop results into the table(data.frame) or even .csv file. I can't handle with that issue by myself.

```
for (i in 1:10000){
      x<-pois(1,40)
      sum<-round(digits = 2, sum(rlnorm(x, log(10), log(5))))
      }
```

Comment: ? `replicate(10000, round(digits = 2, sum(rlnorm(pois(1,40), log(10), log(5)))))` From where is the function `pois()` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a for loop, create an empty vector and then iterate through each position.

```
mySums <- numeric(10000)
for (i in 1:10000){
  x <- rpois(1,40)
  mySums[i] <- round(digits = 2, sum(rlnorm(x, log(10), log(5))))
}
```

It is straightforward to then turn this into a dataframe or any other format you require.

**Edit:** This is assuming you meant to use `rpois()` or something similar.

Comment: @jogo I am aware of that :) This is not my answer, is it? Just fixing what Matt intended to post. I think you should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: Isn't extending the vector slower than replacing elements in a zero-vector. I think I meant zero vector as opposed to Null.

Comment: @MattTriggs Since the loop is of known size, the initiated vector should probably be something like `mySums <- numeric(10000)` or `mySums <- vector(mode="numeric", length=10000)`. `vector()` creates a vector of mode logical and length 0 that must be coerced to numeric in the first step of the loop as well as grown (ie copied to a new section of RAM) in each step.

Comment: My original comment had the vector initialised, but this was edited. I'll change.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to call `rpois()` (and not `pois()`):

```
mySums <- replicate(10000, round(digits=2, sum(rlnorm(rpois(1,40), log(10), log(5)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed, I meant rpois function. I solved it using the next formula:

```
Results=matrix(0,10000,1)

for ( i in 1:10000)
{
  x<-rpois(1,40)
  Results[i,1]<-round(digits = 2, sum(rlnorm(x,log(20), log(4))))
}
```

Comment: `Results[ ,1] <- replicate(10000, round(digits=2, sum(rlnorm(rpois(1,40), log(20), log(4)))))` is faster without for-loop. Or even: `Results <- matrix(replicate(10000, round(digits=2, sum(rlnorm(rpois(1,40), log(20), log(4))))), , 1)`